# Check if Object is of Type

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist, equals

I have a parent class with two types of objects in it. I have to multiple instances of both types into one array list. I need to check if the object is of one type or the other while stepping through the array. What can I use for this? I tried

```
if(estimates.getClass().equals(HulaHoop.class))
```

But then it gives me the alert `'equal()' between objects of inconvertable types 'Class<HulaHoop>' and 'Class<capture of? extends ArrayList>'`.

Comment: Did you try instanceof operator? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Comment: @fabian It was the arraylist, that was a major part of my problem. I just was overlooking it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're comparing the array object itself, not an element of it. `instanceof` is simpler to use.

Comment: This was the actual problem, but all of the other comments were helpful as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the instanceof operator:

```
if (estimates instanceof HulaHoop) {
    ...
}
```